# MySQL slow query even though primary index is being used and good EXPLAIN plan

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

I have a highly trafficked table with 1.3M rows which is seeing a spate of slow queries of the following type:

```
UPDATE app_info SET data1=269223, data2=0, data3=164, last_update='2012-08-30'
WHERE slice_id=7636 AND app_id=375 AND user_id=21012286 AND mode_id=1;
```

Yet, the explain plan for this query indicates an optimal plan (we're using the primary key):

```
explain select * from app_info
where slice_id=7636 and app_id=375 and user_id=21012286 and mode_id=1\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: app_info
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 18
          ref: const,const,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

Here's the slow query log:

```
 Time: 120830  3:23:37
# User@Host: rest_service[rest_service] @ app01.peak.mindjolt.com [10.0.0.174]
# Thread_id: 10091395  Schema: platform  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 68.559347  Lock_time: 0.000045  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1 Rows_affected: 1  Rows_read: 2
# Bytes_sent: 52  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
# InnoDB_trx_id: 575CBF3B9
UPDATE app_info SET data1=269223, data2=0, data3=164, last_update='2012-08-30' WHERE slice_id=7636 AND app_id=375 AND user_id=21012286 AND mode_id=1;
```

About 30% of all queries are taking >1s, and about 10% of all queries are taking >10s (!)

What could be causing this query to run slow? As far as I can tell, the plan is perfect, only one row was scanned, and no time was spent acquiring the lock. So, what goes?

Update: forgot to include server specs, this is on a 64G Quad Xeon X5650 2.66GHz (24 cores), Mysql 5.1.52-rel11.6-log Percona server 11.6, 12 disk PERC H700 RAID Array. This server has worked perfectly fine for a long time (uptime indicate 565 days up).

Update 2: This table has only one index, which is a primary index consisting of the tuple (app_id, user_id, slice_id, mode_id). Additionally, this is a write-only master, three other slave servers handle all reads.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` does not work on UPDATE queries as far a I know so far

Comment: possibly, but doesn't the slow query log show that the update query only scanned one row, just as my explain plan on a modified select query shows?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are indexes on one or more of the columns you are updating, and with that large of an index, it could take some time to flush those indexes and rebuild the necessary parts. I would do an audit of the indexes and remove any which are not giving you highly valuable `select` performance gains. A quick search also turned up [the delay-key-write option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_delay-key-write) (MyISAM only :-/), which may help. The last frontier (if that's actually the issue) would be to look into master-for-write/slave-for-read architecture and then do significantly fewer indexes on your write master server.

**edit** I searched a bit for InnoDB options and found [this SO question](https://serverfault.com/questions/234893/how-to-disable-keys-in-mysql-innodb) on how to temporarily disable keys for them for write operations.

Comment: Great point, didn't factor index update into the equation. Unfortunately, just checked the table and its only index is the (app_id, user_id, slice_id, mode_id) tuple. And the update isn't updating any key column.
By the way, we already have a write-master/read-slave architecture. This is on the master, and reads go to three slave servers.